# How to build a .NET client API for a WCF service

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, api

I have a .NET WCF service which is implemented in a hand full of of projects in VS2010.  Is there any way I can create a new project which merges together all of the service contracts and operation contracts into one DLL to distribute to clients?

In short, I want to distribute a single DLL to clients to hit my WCF service.

I will provide more information if needed, but I'm a bit of a WCF noob.

thanks,
Mark

Comment: Yes, you can do precisely that.  But what is the question, exactly?  Organizing your contracts into a common, self-contained, and independent project is rather straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just the article you're looking for:

WCF the Manual Way... the Right Way ([link](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0809101&page=1))

It goes into detail on how to manually create proxies to do exactly what you're asking for.

Hope it helps!